# How to bypass clearTimeout in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I often access a website, which displays images in a sequential manner. After viewing the first image, the popup-link for the image becomes active after 30 seconds. I want to bypass this timer. So, I looked up the source code of the page, and there I came across the following lines of code-

```
function Window(ID) {

        var lg = JSON.stringify(lg);
        CloseTimeout = setTimeout('Close(' + wID + ',' + nd + ',' + lnkFlag + ');', 30000);
        interval = window.setInterval(function () {
        }, 1000);
    }
```

In line 6,  30000 is the time to wait in milliseconds.

Is there a way to bypass /reduce duration of this timer using some javascript code for all the links ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I deleted my answer as I realized it wouldn't work. Since it looks like the function that's responsible for closing the popup is `CloseWindowOnUpdateTask`, which requires a few potentially difficult to obtain arguments, you'll need to figure out what the appropriate `workID`, `nextTrId` and `lnkFlag` values are, then just call `CloseWindowOnUpdateTask` with those arguments.

Comment: And wow this is poor code.

Comment: It is in your own browser... so just rewrite the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround about your issue could be based on replacing the standard ***setTimeout***.

This is not a polite and correct way, but it's fast enough.

The code:

```
var _setTimeout = window.setTimeout;
window.setTimeout = function (a, b) {
    if ((typeof a === 'string' || a instanceof String) &&
            (a.startsWith('CloseWindowOnUpdateTask') && b == 30000)) {
        _setTimeout(a, 1000);
    } else {
        _setTimeout.apply(null, arguments);
    }
```

}

Comment: +1 A bad hack, but that's probably exactly what the OP needs, and anything else would probably be overkill.